# How do we send php page attribute values to a php class method

Tags: php, oop

How do we send php page attribute values to a php class method?. I want to get php attribute values into a php class method. following is the way i tried.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>

</head>

<body>
  <form id="test" method="post" action="testPhp.php">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="n1" id="name" />
    <input type="submit" value="ADD NAME">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Now I want to get this name value in method in separate php file

```html
testPhp.php
<?php

class getParam{

public function getFormParm(){
$name = $_POST['n1'];
}

}
     
    ?>
```

Comment: You should use proper routung like `ClassName/functionName/params` . Else you will have messy code. In your case you should get it in constructor

Comment: Are you looking for a routing method or do you just want to use the form parameter as a method name?

Comment: If you use NO routing, you shuold use `action = "test.php"` . Its different case if you are using framework which uses mvc

Comment: did you check http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20262/how-to-properly-use-oop-in-php-with-forms

Comment: Yes, I checked it. But I want a standard way to send form parameter values to a php class method directly. Since this is a fundamental thing I though there should be a way to get these parameters directly.

Comment: How you called method 'getFormParm' when action 'testPhp' is submitted?

Comment: Yes, That is my question, Is there a way that you know, how to direct my parameter values to a php class method?

Answer (score 0):

You have no valid action declared as the forms action. Try `$_SERVER['self']` as the form action, like so:

```
<body>
    <form id="test" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['self']?>">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="n1" id="name" />
        <input type="submit" name='submit' value="ADD NAME">
    </form>
</body>
```

And to get the result of this, do the following:

```
<?php 
    echo $_POST['n1'];
?>
```

Comment: Luca, I want to separate my html from php code. So I bring my attribute values in to a separate php file and assign them in to variables there. My action testPhp.php. In this file i want to get the attribute values in a class method like getFormParm().

Comment: I just added another answer, does that answer your question? Also, make sure not to use the `$_SERVER['self']` for that one as your action.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have the class set up, you aren't actually doing anything with the class. Nothing is being executed. You can do something like this:

```
<?php

class getParam{
    public function getFormParm(){
        $name = $_POST['n1'];
        return $name;
    }
}
// This is the part that you are missing
$getParam = new getParam();
echo $getParam->getFormParm();
```

Comment: The bottom two lines can be in any file, as long as you require this file. That achieves the separation of the variables.

Comment: Yes , this is a work around, But I am expecting a support from the php framework. You answer should be worked. But I am finding a much nicer and more manageable way of implementing this.

Comment: I not sure if I am understanding your english correctly, but I don't think PHP has a native implementation of constructing PHP variables from Post variables. You could  do something like this to make it more dynamic:
    
    `public function getFormParm($varName){
        $name = $_POST[$varName];
        return $name;
    }`

Comment: That's what i wanted to know. Whether php has any native implementation for extracting values from POST variables?. I think you know that is in JAVA EE servlet class consist of methods that can be return POST attribute values. So I was expecting something like that. any way thanks for your help

Comment: What I have extracts the values of the post variables and outputs them onto the screen. Are you looking to make PHP Variables with the name of the contents of a POST variable? I.e., Input (in Post): `varname=test` and then creates a php variable of the name `$test`?